# Appodeal Rewarded ads failed to Load

Tags: android, ads, rewardedvideoad

Im solving this issue for about 3 days. Im implementing Rewarded Ads of Appodeal. When I first start my app It works fine . Appodeal onRewardedVideoLoaded function called and it works fine. But After closing the app and running it again. It always calls onRewardedVideoFailedToLoad function and ads do not load. Below is my code.

Please check this code. Thankyou

```
    /** Set up button to show an ad when clicked */
    show_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //ad.show();




            if (Appodeal.isLoaded(Appodeal.REWARDED_VIDEO)) {
                Appodeal.show(getActivity(), Appodeal.REWARDED_VIDEO);
            }

        }
    });


    //appodeal


    Appodeal.setAutoCache(Appodeal.REWARDED_VIDEO, false);

    Appodeal.initialize(getActivity(), appKey, Appodeal.REWARDED_VIDEO);
    // Appodeal.setTesting(true);
    Appodeal.setLogLevel(com.appodeal.ads.utils.Log.LogLevel.verbose);
    Appodeal.cache(getActivity(), Appodeal.REWARDED_VIDEO);

    if (Appodeal.isLoaded(Appodeal.REWARDED_VIDEO)) {
        progress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        System.out.println("Is loaded so enable");
        show_button.setText("Earn Reward");
    }


    Appodeal.setRewardedVideoCallbacks(new RewardedVideoCallbacks() {
        private Toast mToast;

        @Override
        public void onRewardedVideoLoaded() {
            System.out.println("onRewardedVideoLoaded");
            show_button.setEnabled(true);
            progress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            show_button.setText("Earn Reward");
        }

        @Override
        public void onRewardedVideoFailedToLoad() {
            System.out.println("onRewardedVideoFailedToLoad");
            progress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onRewardedVideoShown() {
            System.out.println("onRewardedVideoShown");
            show_button.setEnabled(false);
            show_button.setText("Not Avalible");
            progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onRewardedVideoFinished(int amount, String name) {
            System.out.println(String.format("onRewardedVideoFinished. Reward: %d %s", amount, name));

            SharedPref.putIntPref("rewards_count", SharedPref.getIntPref("rewards_count", getContext()) + amount, getContext());
            //   watcher.RemainingRewards(SharedPref.getIntPref("rewards_count", getContext()));

            UpdateRewards();
        }

        @Override
        public void onRewardedVideoClosed(boolean finished) {
            System.out.println(String.format("onRewardedVideoClosed,  finished: %s", finished));


        }

        void showToast(final String text) {
            if (mToast == null) {
                mToast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(), text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            }
            mToast.setText(text);
            mToast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            mToast.show();
        }
    });


    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar issue, but actually it was connected with framework I used (it turned out after I contacted them), so I'd suggest asking their support directly, usually they respond rather quick + u can message them from LiveChat window on the homepage, right bottom corner. This would be the best way to solve your provlem imo. Not sure that my case will solve your problem, but still it might help you somehow.

i wanted to show skippable and non skippable videos in several projects.

All in all using skippable videos was simple, i only needed to implement GdxAppodeal.VIDEO while initializing.

so to show videos  I used `GdxAppodeal.getInstance().show(GdxAppodeal.VIDEO);`
+
Video callbacks:

```
   GdxAppodeal.getInstance().setVideoCallbacks(new VideoCallback() {
       @Override
        public void onVideoLoaded() { }

        @Override
        public void onVideoFailedToLoad() { }

        @Override
        public void onVideoShown() { }

        @Override
        public void onVideoFinished() { }

        @Override
        public void onVideoClosed() { }
      });
```

important nuance was that u can't set reward settings on site for skippable video.
This only works for rev vids.

So, User will get reward  on RewardedVideoFinished callback